# why angular $http.get to json file return html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I using list from json on my page. I work on localhost, then push to server. Elemets tree looks like:

```
/
|--> about/
|         |--> about.html
|         |--> about.js
|         |--> list.json // first try
|--> smth/
|--> components/
|--> index.html
|--> style.sass
|--> list.json
```

I'm not able to reach the `list.json` file.

I tried using both `./about/list.json` and `about/list.json`, having `list.json` file in the `about` directory.

Then I tried with `list.json` in the root, I used `list.json`.

So I have 2 different errors:

When `list.json` is in `about/` dir - on `localhost` it works fine, but on server I have **404 Error**. This is the code I use:

```
$http.get('./app/list.json').then(function (res) {
  var goods = res.data;
};
```

When `list.json` is in root dir the server returns `index.html` page..

```
$http.get('list.json').then(function (res) {
  var goods = res.data;
};
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The problem seems on the webserver - which webserver do you use? How did you configure it?

Comment: @rpadovani It's a big project and I'm front-end dev so unfortunately I don't know about server a lot..

Comment: @rpadovani but when I make link to sass or pics or for scripts - all dir links is working. or It's a problem just with a $http.get?

Comment: Maybe the server isn't configured to serve the `.json` file. What happens if you try to reach it from the browser?

Comment: @rpadovani when json file is in 'about' dir - 'Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.'
when in root - html. And I think it returned html couse I have routing like 'index.page', so It think that It's not json but page link. It think that 'site.com/list.json' is page

Comment: @rpadovani perhaps I could take info from json not using $http.get?

Comment: The best thing to do is to inform who manage the server that is impossible to reach `.json` files

Comment: Can u share the url that u hit in browser?

Comment: @rpadovani I will clarify , thanks